# Is it possible to create a temporary file that will autodelete after a specific time that it's not read by any other program?

Tags: command-line, scripting, tmp

I'd like to create a temporary file that will be read by multiple scripts after its creation, but I don't have an easy way of monitoring when the last script finishes reading this temporary file to delete it (it may be a different script each time). I'd like to know if there's a standard way of solving this problem with command-line tools that will autodelete this file when it passes a specific interval of time without being read by any program, is it possible? Or the only way to solve this problem would be to figure out a way of knowing when the last script finishes reading this file for deleting it?

Comment: The `stat` command will give you the information you need, but there's no auto-delete mechanism that I know of.

Comment: The `stat` command gives you the last access time of a file in seconds-since-epoch. That could go in a script initiated as a job using `at`. Depending on the outcome of the `stat` and `date +%s`, it will either decide to remove the file, or re-issue an `at` command to re-run itself after a delay based on the last access time plus required delay.

Comment: Thanks @ajgringo619 and @Paul_Pedant... I've checked the `stat` command as well but the problem I faced with it is that I don't have the time that the file was last closed using `stat`... `inotifywait` worked better because it gives me that information. As an example, for testing the `stat` command I've created a small script that reads my file line by line and sleeps 5 seconds in each line, in my case, the `stat` knows that the file was accessed but it doesn't know when it was closed. That's a problem because there may still have some outside program reading the file when it's deleted.

Comment: `stat` is frequently no use at all. The Linux default (set by the `relatime` mount option) does not update `atime` unless (a) an access is made that is newer than the mtime or ctime of the file (essentially shows that a file has been read since changed, but not other recent accesses). And (b) previous access time is more than 24 hours out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [taiyu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/623550/444310)'s answer using `inotifywait` I've created a `node.js` solution to this problem... It required more details than I expected when I asked it. Sorry if that's not the right place for posting node.js code but the asynchronous nature of the language made things simpler for me... My solution is the following:

```javascript
const fs = require('fs');
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const file='/home/user/hugefile.csv';
let counter = 0; // counter used for identifying how many times the file was opened and closed by a different program

const child = spawn('/bin/bash', [ '-c', `inotifywait --format=%e -q -m -e access,close ${file}` ])

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    let line = data.toString().split('\n').filter(item => item); // get events inside a javascript array and filter empty values
    // loop through the inotify events
    line.forEach(function(event) {
        if ( event === "ACCESS" )
            counter++;
        else if ( event === "CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE" )
            counter--;

        // asynchronous function that checks the value of counter after 10 seconds
        async function timer() {
            await sleep(10000);
            console.log(counter);
            if ( counter === 0 ){
                fs.unlinkSync(file); // erase file
                console.log("tmpfile erased!")
                process.exit();
            }
        }
        timer();
    });
});

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Basically, I used `inotifywait` as a basis for solving the problem... I just need to execute this script after creating the temporary file and it will erase the file after all other programs finish reading the file (after 10 seconds).

---

OBS: My problem trying to solve it with `bash` is that when I make a function run as a process with `&` I lose control of the new values of global variables inside that function. So I couldn't get the `counter` state using the same logic that I've used on `node.js`...  If someone knows a workaround for this, feel free to write in the comments here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using inotifywait, you can add the following to your scripts that access the file.

```
if ! inotifywait $FILE -t $SECONDS >/dev/null 2>&1
then rm $FILE
fi &
```

The script will spawn a process that waits until something accesses $FILE.
if something does, it does nothing and exits.
if the timeout is reached after $SECONDS, it will remove the file

alternatively using a seperate script, that you run at creation of the file

```
while inotifywait $FILE -t $SECONDS >/dev/null 2>&1
do sleep 1
done
rm $FILE
```

it will loop whenever the file is accessed,
if nothing accesses it within the timeout, it breaks and removes the file.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me the basis for solving this problem... The only problem with this answer is that if a script stays with the file open for an undetermined period of time without closing the file your solutions will timeout before the time. I tried to create a bash solution but I didn't manage to do it... Although with node.js using inotifywait it was simpler... I'll post my solution as well.